# Getting Angular Example to Run

Tags: angularjs

I am learning angularJS, and am having trouble getting the following example code, from a training video, to run.  Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

It stopped working when I changed it from the 2nd version, shown below.  The 2nd version works fine, but when I try to modularize the controller, it breaks.

```
<html ng-app="demoApp">
    <head>
        <title>Hello World, AngularJS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="SimpleController">
            <br/>
            <input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
            <br/>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | orderBy:salary">
                    {{ cust.name | uppercase}} -
                    {{ cust.city | lowercase }} -
                    {{ cust.salary | currency }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script>
        var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',[]);

        demoApp.controller('SimpleController', ['', function($scope){
            $scope.customers = [
                {name: 'John Smith',     city: 'Phoenix',     salary: 90000, hired: '2014-04-04'},
                {name: 'Jenny Linn',     city: 'New York',    salary: 94000, hired: '2014-04-04'},
                {name: 'Johnson Holmes', city: 'Los Angeles', salary: 96000, hired: '2014-04-04'},
                {name: 'Thomas Muffin',  city: 'Chicago',     salary: 80000, hired: '2014-04-17'}
            ]}])
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Version that works:

```
 <html ng-app="">
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="SimpleController">
      <input type="text" ng-model="nameInput" /> <span style="font-weight:bold"> {{ nameInput }}</span>
      <h3>Listing1</h3>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter: nameInput | orderBy: 'city' ">
          {{ cust.name | uppercase }} - {{ cust.city }} - {{ cust.salary }} - {{ cust.hired | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
    function SimpleController($scope) {
    $scope.customers =    [
        {name: 'John Smith',      city: 'Phoenix',       salary: 90000,  hired: '2014-04-04'},
        {name: 'Jenny Linn',      city: 'New York',      salary: 94000,  hired: '2014-04-04'},
        {name: 'Johnson Holmes',  city: 'Los Angeles',   salary: 96000,  hired: '2014-04-04'},
        {name: 'Thomas Muffin',   city: 'Chicago',       salary: 80000,  hired: '2014-04-17'}
    ];    }
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems here.

1. First, you need to inject the string literal `'$scope'` into your controller.
2. Your angular script files must be rendered before your other angular-related files. i.e to put your `<script src = 'google api here'>` before your all other javascript tags.

   ```
   <html ng-app="demoApp">
   <head>
   <title>Hello World, AngularJS</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div ng-controller="SimpleController">
       <br/>
       <input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
       <br/>
       <ul>
           <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | orderBy:salary">
               {{ cust.name | uppercase}} -
               {{ cust.city | lowercase }} -
               {{ cust.salary | currency }}
           </li>
       </ul>
       </div>
        <!-- load your angular core script files first -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',[]);

          demoApp.controller('SimpleController', ['$scope', function($scope){
            $scope.customers = [
           {name: 'John Smith',     city: 'Phoenix',     salary: 90000, hired: '2014-04-04'},
           {name: 'Jenny Linn',     city: 'New York',    salary: 94000, hired: '2014-04-04'},
           {name: 'Johnson Holmes', city: 'Los Angeles', salary: 96000, hired: '2014-04-04'},
           {name: 'Thomas Muffin',  city: 'Chicago',     salary: 80000, hired: '2014-04-17'}
       ]}])
        </script>
    </body>
   </html>
   ```

Here is the [working plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/JDcKLy0Xb31qOi4XQkrd?p=preview).

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass $scope into your controller in the modularized example

```
demoApp.controller('SimpleController', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.customers = [
            {name: 'John Smith',     city: 'Phoenix',     salary: 90000, hired: '2014-04-04'},
            {name: 'Jenny Linn',     city: 'New York',    salary: 94000, hired: '2014-04-04'},
            {name: 'Johnson Holmes', city: 'Los Angeles', salary: 96000, hired: '2014-04-04'},
            {name: 'Thomas Muffin',  city: 'Chicago',     salary: 80000, hired: '2014-04-17'}
        ]}])
```

Comment: Appreciate it.  I made that change, but that alone doesn't seem to fix it :(